# Минус вопросу и всем ответам в нём

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Могу ошибаться, но показалось, что в [Как из массива получить значения и разбить их на буквы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718158/) одновременно добавилось по минусу к вопросу и каждому ответу в нём. Такое же впечатление было в [Как сделать градиентную резиновую кнопку с косым краем (в виде трапеции) и закругленными углами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/689904/), но там один из минусованных ответов удалён.

Комментариев к вопросу и ответам при этом не добавилось.

Выглядит, как будто один пользователь проголосовал "против" всего подряд, и молча ушёл.

Как можно проверить, что происходит?

Comment: Демократия происходит. Так можно делать. Да, не все употребляют свои голоса с пользой, но это лишь статистическая погрешность.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на вопрос. Добавил минусов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Пожалуйста ;) Если скажете, за что минус, буду признателен.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky за ответ куском кода без комментариев

Comment: а еще - это дубликат вопроса от того же автора: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717724/, точнее - просьба решить более простую задачу

Comment: и что самое забавноее - на первоначальном вопросе стоял тег [tag:javascript], но один участник с репутацией < 2000 его снял, еще двое - почему-то подтвердило эту правку. после этого участник, снявший метку, дал ответ в псевдокоде. топикастер сдался и задал вопрос заново, в более простом виде и без упоминаня слова "алгоритм".

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо за пояснение к минусу. [Дополнил ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718177/208926).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Голосование субъективно по определению. В свою очередь, конечно же, мы просим участников использовать голоса по назначению — для оценки качества содержимого сайта так, чтобы лучшие и наиболее полезные сообщения всегда были «вверху». Все же, повторюсь, голосование — субъективно. С другой стороны, чтобы как–то влиять на откровенно неправильное использования голосов (то есть не по назначению), в системе есть механизмы автоматической отмены голосования, которые срабатывают во многих случаях. Если у вас есть подозрения, что голоса были использованы не по назначению, вы всегда можете написать мне в [общем чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или [на почту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) или связаться с командой развития сообществ через [обратную связь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Мы проверим ваши догадки и откатим голоса вручную, если имело место серьезное нарушение.

---

Я проверил результаты голосования в указанных вами вопросах дополнительно. Голосовали совершенно разные люди, в большинстве случаев, не являющиеся авторами ответов в самих вопросах. На данный момент, я не вижу причины откатывать голоса.

Comment: стоит явно сказать, что цель голосования—улучшение сайта. Иначе найдутся люди, которые ваше "голосование субъективно" воспримут как разрешение минусы ставить всем вопросам с id на 7 заканчивающихся. То есть у человека для себя по крайней мере должен быть ответ как голос помогает сообществу.

Comment: вот посмотрите [*"голоса субъективны"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712792/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9/712793?noredirect=1#comment1081784_712793) уже используют как аргумент, что можно наплевать на цели сайта ("*никому ничего не должны*")

Comment: @jfs Использование голосов не по назначению != субъективность голосования. Голосование — субъективно, но голоса следует использовать по назначению — для сортировки содержимого сайта так, чтобы качественные сообщения были всегда наверху. Субъективность самого процесса голосования, вероятно, побороть невозможно, так как мы люди, а не машины.

Comment: я это знаю. Проблема в размытости значения фразы *"Голосование субъективно"*, что на  практике (см. выше) ведёт к неправильной её интерпретации. В таких случаях, стоит уменьшить размытость: либо не используйте эту фразу вообще, либо всегда дополняйте её явным упоминанием зачем голосование существует. То есть: *«голоса следует использовать по назначению — для сортировки содержимого сайта так, чтобы качественные сообщения были всегда наверху.»* лучше в сам ответ поместить. От себя добавлю, что даже если ответ один, то голосование можно использовать, чтобы *полезность* ответа отразить.